# How to save multiple files as CSV from my table based on the change of one column

Tags: mysql

I have three columns in SQL in my table:
ID - Time - Velocity
I have 1500 unique IDs
I want to save the results of the table into 1500 CSV files with ID name on it. Any suggestions would be very helpful!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will need to run 1500 SQL queries... or use dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to your SQL database using a simple Java program. Extract the id column into an ArrayList. Once you have array list write your files based on the entries in the array list.

```
ArrayList <String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery( "SELECT ID FROM TABLE_NAME" );
for (int i=0; rs.next(); i++)
 result.add( rs.getString(i) );
```

result now has all your IDs. Write the files using the values in result